# passing complex structure from client to webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, web-services, json

My webservice gets an item and should store it and it's fields:

```
[WebMethod]
public void StoreItem(Item item)
{
    item.Store();
}
```

There are 4 types of fields but when the client pass the Item object - the fields will not pass correctly since it is an interface and not implementation.
One possible solution - **which not help me at all** is to use instead the following webservice:

```
[WebMethod]
public void StoreItem(Item item, frstTypeField[] fields12, scndTypeField[] fields,
    thrdTypeField[] fields3, frthTypeField[] fields4)
{
    //append fields to item and then store
}
```

I don't like this solution because I need to change the webservice when I add a new field type. In addition - Item is part of an order so there is another webservice that stores an order. So how can I pass the fields for each item in the order?

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Change all your types to strings and Dictionary<String, String> to match JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Raynos ~ not necessarily. `WebMethod`s have the capacity to expect and accept a defined type from an AJAX call as well. But it's true that JS objects immediately map to `string`s, `int`s and `Dictionary<string,string>` normally.

Comment: @Raynos: I am using the default asp.net serializer to JSON so I can "pass" objects from the client and to the server and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:
I made a transition object named "TransitionItem" which holds 4 properties where each property is an array with type of one of the fields types.
Within this transition object I created method called ToItem that "translates" the TransitionItem to a "normal" Item with all the interfaces and stuff.
So my webservice now looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
public void StoreItem(TransitionItem tItem)
{
    IItem item=tItem.ToItem();
    item.Store();
}
```

This is how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make all relevant information public properties and also make sure all of them are xml serializeable (or provide custom serialization via the `IXmlSerializable` interface).

Comment: I am using JSON serializer but this is not the problem. How does the server will know to which type deserialize each field?

Comment: @Naor: You're deserializing to a particular type; it requires that type include a parameterless constructor and public properties. It just matches by name and each response is cast as the type of that property. If it is more complicated, you can create a custom serializer. An example of this is serializing a MailMessage, as described here:
http://nayyeri.net/archive/2008/3 (for some reason, the link to that article always redirects me to the front page of his blog, but the article was written Mar 2, 2008, so it's at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @Michael Blackburn: I can write JSON deserializer and serializer, but the interface I wanto to deserialize IField is used in two different places to implement 4 types of fields in each place. So with your solution I need to implement two serializers that actually does the same..

Comment: @Naor: I think you've solved the problem with your transition object. The reason you have to do this is because you can't deserialize to an interface. You have to deserialize to a class. An interface only defines a contract; classes which implement that interface may have MANY other attributes which the deserializer wouldn't know what to do with.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by sending in a JSON object to my WebMethod with a `__type` property equal to the qualified class (e.g. `{item:{'__type':'MyNamespace.Item'}}`.

But that can be a bit tedious if your `Item` object is somewhat complex.

What I did to start is to publish a `WebMethod` that takes no parameters, and just returns a newly instantiated object of whatever type I wanted to pass in to my real `WebMethod`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static Item GetItem () {
    return new Item {
        // set properties, whatever
    };
}
```

Call that from your jQuery, and use something like JSON2 to inspect the returned object.

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'default.aspx/GetItem',
        data : '{}',
        // blah
        success : function (m) {
            alert (JSON.stringify(m.d));
        }
    });

});
```

... then just use the resulting JSON string as a template. Modify as needed.

Comment: Neil Ilagan: according to your solution, each time the user creates an item or a field of an item he triggers webservice call? isn't it create many unnecessary calls?

Comment: @Naor ~ no, I meant that if he was having trouble trying to serialize a JS object back to a complex type in his WebMethod, that he may try to inspect how his complex type translates back to JS first, copy that to notepad or something, and put it somewhere in JS code as a template. Only needs to be called once in a test environ. :D

Comment: Neil Ilagan: Now I understand. I prefer not to use the __type thing since it makes dependency between the client and the server and force you to use asp.NET.

Comment: @Naor ~ in that case, you should look into @Raynos' suggestion above. JSON literals normally parse into `Dictionary<string,string>` as key-value pairs for most anything more complex than primitive types.